# looking for a cached function call mechanism

Tags: haskell

I'm calling a database ([EventStore](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/eventstore)) that recommend using the same connection for the entire life span of your app. I want to implement a cached call for that, but the only thing I'm finding is memoization caching in that way (lib [io-memoize](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/io-memoize)) :

```
import Database.EventStore
import System.IO.Memoize

getCachedEventStoreConnection :: Settings -> ConnectionType -> IO (IO (Connection))
getCachedEventStoreConnection settings connectionType = once $ connect settings connectionType
```

What I would like is more a signature like that :

getCachedEventStoreConnection :: Settings -> ConnectionType -> IO Connection

otherwise I'm obliged to keep that IO (IO (Connection)) as a "global fct" that I'm passing everywhere which is bad for modularity...

Comment: I don't think the way you use `once` makes sense: you should not pass around the `IO (IO (Connection))` (that wouldn't actually memoise anything but always open a new connection), but rather evaluate it once and then pass around the `IO (Connection)`. But even that does, I think, not buy you anything over simply calling `connect` once and passing around the `Connection`. But I could be wrong here.

Comment: Your app needs state. The `Connection` should be part of that state.

Comment: https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2017/06/readert-design-pattern may be of use.

Comment: @leftaroundabout What `once` buys you is this: if you never actually need to use the `Connection`, it isn't even opened, so a run of your app that doesn't use the database never actually calls `connect`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> otherwise I'm obliged to keep that IO (IO (Connection)) as a "global fct" that I'm passing everywhere which is bad for modularity.

Unfortunately, caching calls doesn't help eliminate function arguments: instead of passing around the result of a cached call, you must pass around the cache instead. There's no getting around it; part of the hair shirt you wear when choosing Haskell is that *all* the data a function wants to use must be made explicit in its type, so if part of your application needs a database `Connection`, there's nothing for it but to pass a `Connection` to that part of your application (and, by extension, all its callers).

There is some sugar like `ReaderT` you can sprinkle around to make things a bit more convenient, making it appear as though you're not passing around function arguments, but at the end of the day that's exactly what they're doing under the hood.

However, I reject your claim that this is bad for modularity. If you *did* have an implicit cache, this would *break* modularity: you would not be able to lift that function out of this application into a library and use it in many applications without *also* lifting the cache out. That is, the cache and any operations that use it become coupled -- one must lift them all or none, the exact opposite of modularity.* If the database connection is a function argument instead of an implicit cache, it can be lifted independently of lifting the chunk of code that creates the connection once at app startup.

* And suppose you do lift out all the operations and the implicit cache into a library. Now two downstream libraries depend on and use yours; do you get two caches, that must be separately initialized and therefore is maybe less efficient, or do you get one shared cache which therefore bleeds effects from the one library into the other and therefore is maybe less correct? A difficult choice -- one that should have to be made carefully and explicitly by the downstream users, not by the library with the cache in it.

Comment: the issue I have is that I'm trying to to give the ability in my project to change the database (EventStore here) by using Interface segregation. This getCachedConnection is something specific only this database not for another one... I see how I can deal with it if I do an eDSL (which is hard so far because I'm streaming things and the lib I'm using has some missing features...) but this is something I can't express in an Interface because this connection data type is an EventStore data type...

Comment: In OOP I would have done a PersistedStreamSettings parameter (Map Key Object and use some subtyping polymorphism) but in Haskell I don't know what to do with this complex data type like this EventStore Connection one... I hope you can follow ... it's hard to explain my issue in a stackoverflow question...

Comment: and to make a confession, I knew that, what I was asking sounds fishy, like storing something in shared memory under the hood... but it is a tempting shortcut in my context... haskell is here to keep me in the right path lol –

Comment: @NicolasHenin If you can put in enough details to make the question answerable, I'll be happy to take a shot at it. Haskell program design is indeed a different beast than design in other languages in some ways.

Comment: I've found a solution by using type variables and it works perfectly, haskell is a beautiful beast :-)